# Visualforce page is not redirecting to specific VF pages with associated record types

Tags: visualforce, record-type, redirect

For Account, we have few record types. we want to have the related vf page displayed when a specific record type is selected.

However, upon selecting a record type, the below vf page is not directing the VF new record page specific to record type. it is displaying nullpointer exception.

We also have a domain for our instance.

Am i missing something here?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="NewAccountExtension" action="{!redirectToNewVFPage}">
</apex:page>
```

.

```
public with sharing class NewAccountExtension {

    public String recordTypeId;

    public NewAccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardController std) {

    }

    public Pagereference redirectToNewVFPage(){
        Pagereference pg = null;
        if(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') != null){
            recordTypeId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');
            if(recordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Finance_Account').getRecordTypeId()){
                pg = new Pagereference('https://avantegrande.cs50.my.salesforce.com/apex/fin_new_account');

            }else if(recordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Logistics_Account').getRecordTypeId()){
                pg = new Pagereference('https://avantegrande.cs50.my.salesforce.com/apex/logi_account');
            }
            pg.setRedirect(true);
            return pg;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're having issues when receiving the record type, please double check your record type developer name too, just to make sure you have the correct id. I hope the code below can help you.

```
public with sharing class NewAccountExtension {

    private ApexPages.StandardController standardController{get; set;}

    public NewAccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        standardController = controller;
    }

    public PageReference redirectPage(){
        Pagereference pg = null;
        Account record = (Account) standardController.getRecord();
        Id recordTypeId = record.RecordType.Id;
        if(recordTypeId != null){
            if(recordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('TypeA').getRecordTypeId()) {
                pg = new Pagereference('/apex/accountRecordTypeA');

            } else if(recordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('TypeB').getRecordTypeId()) {
                pg = new Pagereference('/apex/accountRecordTypeB');
            }
            pg.getParameters().put('id', record.Id);
            pg.setRedirect(true);
            return pg;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a clear description of what your code paste changed or fixed relative to the original question?

Comment: Thanks Pablo - I have double checked the id's to no avail. the page is not directing to any page after selecting the record type. even when directed to generic sites (https://google.com) also its not redireting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're calling the wrong Describe API method to get your Record Type Id.

```
    if(recordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Finance_Account').getRecordTypeId()){
```

`Finance_Account` looks like it is probably the *Developer Name* of the Record Type, not the label. Confusingly, `getRecordTypeInfosByName()` returns Record Types by the user-visible label. This would return `null` and trigger your `NullPointerException`.

To cure this, you can just switch to the new method `getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()`.